# behavior of absolutely positioned element without specified top,right,bottom,left, etc

Tags: css, position, absolute

Given a dom element that has set height and width, and is set position:absolute, is there a predictable positioning for the element if it doesn't have any positioning specified (like top, right, bottom, and left properties)? Does the position default to left:0, top:0? Or does the element stay where it originally was positioned on the page?

Or does the positioning differ from browser to browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example using jsfiddle.
  http://jsfiddle.net/hPJa8/

Most browsers seem to position the element in its natural position, but then subsequent elements will not take into account the absolutely positioned element when they are placed onto the page. This results in the subsequent elements overlapping.

Answer (score 0):

The top left corner of the element stays where it would be if the position of the element was static. Unfortunately, it is not a strict definition.

Take an image as an example. Would we consider it as an inline or block element? (Most browser say inline). Should we consider line break caused by image? (Most browser act as if it's size is zero.) Where should we put it vertically? Choices are: at the the top of the line, at the baseline, at current font height, at image height; adding spans adds choices. The way IE answers this question changed recently AFAIK.

So, do expect differences from browser to browser.

Comment: Hi, we used play chess at MFO, it would be cool to get the old team back: https://lichess.org/team/mfo.